# Why is a String that is null returned as java.lang.Object@.?

Tags: graphql-java

My understanding is that null is an acceptable value in a graphql response.
So I must either have misunderstood something or i am doing something fundamentally wrong because now i am getting "java.lang.Object@7deb1b9" instead of null.

```
schema {
  query: Query
}

type Query {
  greeting: String
}
```

Graphql looking like this:

```
        final Builder vContextBuilder = new Builder()
                .of("locale", mLocale)
                .of("securityContext", mSecurityContext);

        final ExecutionInput vExecutionInput = ExecutionInput
                .newExecutionInput()
                .query(mQuery)
                .context(vContextBuilder)
                .build();

        final InputStream vSchemaInputStream = Thread
                .currentThread()
                .getContextClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream(SCHEMA_FILE_URI);

        final TypeDefinitionRegistry vTypeDefinitionRegistry = new SchemaParser()
                .parse(new InputStreamReader(vSchemaInputStream));

        final RuntimeWiring vRuntimeWiring = RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
                .type("Query", typeWiring -> typeWiring
                        .dataFetcher("greeting", new GreetingFetcher())
                        )
                .build();

        final GraphQLSchema vGraphQLSchema = new SchemaGenerator()
                .makeExecutableSchema(vTypeDefinitionRegistry, vRuntimeWiring);

        final GraphQL vGraphQL = GraphQL.newGraphQL(vGraphQLSchema)
                .build();

        final ExecutionResult vExecutionResult = vGraphQL.execute(vExecutionInput);

        final Map<String, Object> toSpecificationResult = vExecutionResult.toSpecification();
```

And the Greetingfetcher:

```
public class GreetingFetcher extends StaticDataFetcher {

    public GreetingFetcher() {
        super("Hello!");
        //super(null);
    }
}
```

Query:

```
query {
  greeting
}
```

Response from `super("Hello!");`:

```
{
    "data": {
        "greeting": "Hello!"
    }
}
```

Response from `super(null);`:

```
{
    "data": {
        "greeting": "java.lang.Object@7deb1b9"
    }
}
```

Should the response not be:

```
{
    "data": {
        "greeting": null
    }
}
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: `null` itself is a type in java.

Comment: Have you tried running through the code with a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the imports.
Eclipse had added `import graphql.nextgen.GraphQL;` when i changed that to `import graphql.GraphQL;` everything worked fine.